# How to run script in macos with launchd without singe-user mode (with verbose mode)

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm trying to set up a script to automatically execute when the computer is shut down or restarted. The solution I found is to use a **launchd** in combination with **bash** script that will run on login and catch the **SIGTERM** signal indefinitely. But the **launchd** runs the script in **single-user** mode in which some of the commands are missing.

Is there a way to force the **launchd** to run the script in **verbose** mode, or any other way to auto-execute the script?

I tried to register launcher from the following places, the result is the same

1. ~/Library/LaunchAgents/script.plist
2. /Library/LaunchAgents/script.plist
3. /Library/LaunchDaemons/script.plist

   **script.plist**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>local.main.vaultctlstopper</string>

     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
       <string>/path/to/my/bash/script</string>
     </array>

     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>

     <key>StandardOutPath</key>
     <string>/path/to/log</string>

     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/path/to/error/log</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   **script.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   function logout() {
     # here need to use diskutil and gpg, also to have root privileges
     exit
   }

   trap 'logout' SIGTERM

   while true; do
     :&
   done
   ```

   Errors

   1. diskutil

   ```
   Unable to run because unable to use the DiskManagement framework.
   Common reasons include, but are not limited to, the DiskArbitration
   framework being unavailable due to being booted in single-user mode.
   ```

   1. gpg (can not load libintl.8.dylib library )

   ```
   dyld[90721]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
     Referenced from: <E3421065-D8FB-3482-925D-B5215101AE0B> /usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.4.3/bin/gpg
     Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (code signature in <C59C6AEC-6FF0-34F8-8328-93F7F2130CE1> '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' not valid for use in process: system is shutting down), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (code signature in <C59C6AEC-6FF0-34F8-8328-93F7F2130CE1> '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' not valid for use in process: system is shutting down), '/usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (code signature in <C59C6AEC-6FF0-34F8-8328-93F7F2130CE1> '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' not valid for use in process: system is shutting down), '/usr/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (code signature in <C59C6AEC-6FF0-34F8-8328-93F7F2130CE1> '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' not valid for use in process: system is shutting down), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (code signature in <C59C6AEC-6FF0-34F8-8328-93F7F2130CE1> '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' not valid for use in process: system is shutting down), '/usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (code signature in <C59C6AEC-6FF0-34F8-8328-93F7F2130CE1> '/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21.1/lib/libintl.8.dylib' not valid for use in process: system is shutting down), '/usr/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
   ```